# Is there a way to call Karate's feature file scenario from Cucumber feature files scenario?

Tags: cucumber, karate, scenarios

I would like to reuse my Karate scenarios in my Cucumber's feature file scenario. Any idea on how to implement or is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be using the Java API: https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-api

So in your "normal" Cucumber step-definitions:

```
Map<String, Object> result = Runner.runFeature("classpath:demo/java/from-java.feature", args, true);
```

But please read this thread also: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/444#issuecomment-419852761

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. :-)